# How best to set up a large user database like facebook for example

Tags: php, web

I have a site with over 15,000 signups presently (both legitimate users, activated users, and unscrupulous entities).

I set up the signup in such a way that for every signup, a folder is created with an `index php` file to redirect anyone that tries to access the folder.

I got a new shared hosting server recently and i got confused when they restricted file count to about 50,000 15,000 * 2 is 30,000 already and some users have uploaded files and images on the site already.

Is that structure a good one? i mean creating a new folder for each user signups?

The server is a Linux and the scripting language is PHP

**Edited** I create folders for each users because I want to distinguish each users files as each users can upload files like pictures, pdfs, docs etc.

Do I keep all files whatsoever in just one folder?

Comment: a directory for each user? no that's ridiculous

Comment: Oh really? So which is best? After storing the users information in the database? I should create a folder for all images and another for all documents and reference their full paths in the database right?

Comment: @Dagon and others what do you mean by the question is too broad? Please explain yourselves. These flags are becoming too much thus pissing me off. It's a question about my present project.

Answer (score 0):

If you be storing major information's within a file for each signups (eg: including "password, email, phone, credit card"...etc) will be a bad idea.

MySQL will store them in a better way, also; there a lot of scripts you can use.

If you want to build it your own, I suggest you learn more about PHP of handling user registrations. It does take a lot of time and energy!

Comment: Which kind of script handles user registration well? I am actually a PHP developer. I have created registration systems a lot of time. I save every single thing on a `MySql` database but i made the folder that way because  i want each users files to be unique to a folder what do you think about that?